# Regular Expression to match first word with a character in each line

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex that finds the first word in each line that contains the character `a`.
For a string like:

```
The cat ate the dog
and the mouse
```

The expression should find `cat and`
So far, I have:

```
/\b\w*a\w*\b/g
```

However this will return every match in each line, not just the first match (`cat ate and`).
What is the easiest way to only return the first occurrence?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are onluy looking for words without numbers and underscores (`\w` would include those), I'd advise to maybe use:

```
(?i)^.*?(?<!\S)([b-z]*a[a-z]*)(?!\S)
```

And use whatever is in the 1st capture group. See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/2EaiLJ/1). Or, if supported:

```
(?i)^.*?\K(?<!\S)[b-z]*a[a-z]*(?!\S)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/A7YxJe/1).

Please note that I used lookaround to assert that the word is not inbetween anything other than whitespace characters. You may also use word-boundaries if you please and swap those lookarounds for `\b`. Also, depending on your application you can probably scratch the inline case-insensitive switch to a 'flag'. For example, if you happen to use JavaScript `/^.*?(?<!\S)([b-z]*a[a-z]*)(?!\S)/gmi` should probably be your option. See for example:

```js
var myString = "The cat ate the dog\nand the mouse";
var myRegexp = new RegExp("^.*?(?<!\S)([b-z]*a[a-z]*)(?!\S)", "gmi");
m = myRegexp.exec(myString);
while (m != null) {
  console.log(m[1])
  m = myRegexp.exec(myString);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match a word using `\w` you might also use a negated character class matching any character except `a` or a newline.

Then match a word that consists of at least an `a` char with word boundaries `\b`

```
^[^a\n\r]*\b([^\Wa]*a\w*)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[^a\n\r]*\b` Optionally match any character except a or a newline
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\Wa]*a\w*` Optionally match a word character without a, then match a and optional word characters
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2LX4TI/1)

Using whitespace boundaries on the left and right:

```
^[^a\n\r]*(?<!\S)([^\Wa]*a\w*)(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4BeqvA/1)

Comment: Can not `([^\Wa]*a\w*)` be simplified to `(\w*a\w*)`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, that will also match. I used  `([^\Wa]*a\w*)` to prevent backtracking over `\w` for the `a` character.

Comment: That sounds familiar. It's worth a mention (which has now been achieved) for its educational value.

Answer (score 2):

The text could be matched with the regular expression

```
(?=(\b[a-z]*a[a-z]*\b)).*\r?\n
```

with the multiline and case-indifferent flags set. For each match capture group 1 contains the first word (comprised only of letters) in a line that contains an "a". There are no matches in lines that do not contain an "a".

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qSVbwc/1)

The expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(?=                # begin a positive lookahead
  \b               # match a word boundary
  ([a-z]*a[a-z]*)  # match a word containing an "a" and save to
                   # capture group 1
)
.*\r?\n            # match the remainder of the line including the
                   # line terminator
```